# Twitter HTTP Status code with their custom codes

Tags: http, twitter, http-status-codes, rfc, web-standards

Twitter uses an Error Code message system with their API: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes Look under "Error Codes."

I am wondering what HTTP Status code they use for ones that do not correspond to an HTTP status code, for example 231 "User must verify login"

Does anyone know? I am modeling a similar system and am using them as a model.

Alternately, what would be the best approach, I thinking maybe 422 for unprocessable entity for one's that do not correspond since it's fairly generic, but am open to suggestions on this.

Comment: The twitter error codes on the page are not HTTP response codes.  Rather they are included in the body of the response.

Comment: Yes, correct @EdgarR, I am aware of this. But they must include an HTTP status code by default, this question is directed to that aspect.

Comment: It is unclear from the documentation and I do not know.  The only two status codes that mention a possible error code are 400 and 403.  There appears to be no specific mapping of possible error codes to those two HTTP responses.  In addition, there are clear associations like HTTP response code 420 and Error code 88.